# How to make Redirect from WRONG URL to CORRECT ( htLM -> htML )

Tags: html, redirect

Problem :
application was deployed to the client :

now we discovered that in one of the links was mistake:

```
www.blablalba...com\File.htLM instead of  
www.blablalba...com\File.htML
```

ML <-> LM

Host base on PHP ( bluehost.com )
I have full access to the server.
I created this page with name **File.htLM**  and was trying to redirect to correct address,
but browser opens it as text file..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.SUPER-TRUPER.COM/GOOD.html">
    <title>Page Redirection</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I just added to the settings new MIME extension htlm
But it still opening like text file..

User Defined MIME Types
**MIME Type ▾   Extension(s)**
text/html   htlm

Comment: Err, overwrite the file containing a mistake with a corrected copy?

Comment: I'm guessing that the link to the page is something that can't be change retrospectively - I'm assuming "deployed to the client" is some kind of client local component that references the file.

Comment: @iUser in your update to the question you're missing the "." in the extension. See my answer.

Comment: unfortunately, this is iphone app, so it is possible to fix problem by correct the link.. only in next update. But now I'm looking for temporary soulution to fix the bug on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suspect this would be because .htlm wouldn't be a type recognised by the server, and as such, isn't being served with the correct MIME type, so the browser doesn't know to treat it as html.

If you're using Apache you could add this to a .htaccess file

```
AddType text/html .htlm
```

Though if you're using Apache with a .htaccess file you could just add this to redirect the page for you

```
Redirect /file.htlm /file.html
```